# Connecting unused MIPI data lane in schematics and PCB layout

Tags: camera, bus, csi

I am using a MIPI to parallel bridge in one of my designs. The bridge takes in inputs from a MIPI camera and sends the parallel data to a processor. I am using only 2 data lanes (of the 4 data lanes) available in MIPI bridge input.

Can you please let me know how to connect the unused (2) data lanes from a PCB design  perspective (eg: leaving them unconnected or connecting them to ground) and its purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave them disconnected. You will also configure both end chips to use only 2 data lanes so they will completely discard the remaining other lanes. I would recommend *NOT* to ground the other lanes.